# In R, opening an object saved to Excel through shell.exec

Tags: r, excel, shell

I would like to be able to open files quickly in Excel after saving them.  I learned from  R opening a specific worksheet in a excel workbook using shell.exec 1 on SO

On my Windows system, I can do so with the following code and could perhaps turn it into a function: saveOpen <_ function {... .  However, I suspect there are better ways to accomplish this modest goal.

I would appreciate any suggestions to improve this multi-step effort.

```
# create tiny data frame
df  <- data.frame(names = c("Alpha", "Baker"), cities = c("NYC", "Rome"))
# save the data frame to an Excel file in the working directory
save.xls(df, filename "test file.xlsx")
# I have to reenter the file name and add a forward slash for the paste() command below to create a proper file path
name  <- "/test file.xlsx"
# add the working directory path to the file name
file  <- paste0(getwd(), name)
# with shell and .exec for Windows, open the Excel file
shell.exec(file = file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to create a helper function to make this easier? How about

```
save.xls.and.open <- function(dataframe, filename, ...) {
    save.xls(df, filename=filename, ...)
    cmd <- file.path(getwd(), filename)
    shell.exec(cmd)
}
```

then you just run

```
save.xls.and.open(df, filename ="testfile.xlsx")
```

I guess it doesn't seem like all that many steps to me.